# AVG SiteSafety plugin took over Chrome, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, avg-antivirus

Whenever I open a new tab, I get this awful new tab page from AVG SiteSafety.  Not sure how it got there, but I can't get rid of it.  I deleted it from my extensions by going:

Settings -> Extensions -> Remove AVG SiteSafety.

That didn't work.  I then tried to select the 'restore default new tab' on the AVG new tab eyesore, and that didn't work.

I then decided to try to go to chrome://plugins, and it was still there.  I had the option to disable it, so I did, but then whenever I start chrome or open a new page, the page refreshes a thousand times a second and has rendered chrome useless.  Is there a way I can find any trace of this AVG malware and completely purge it from my system?

Comment: Maybe this page may help: http://superuser.com/questions/468524/chrome-new-tab-page-changed-but-i-want-it-back

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you uninstall it through the Control Panel as well.

Answer (score 0):

If removing from control panel failed, you can try third-party softwares [like adcleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) to do the removal for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't in the control panel, you can try uninstalling AVG completely and then see if that fixes it. If it's ok after that you can then reinstall AVG but select advanced install. You can then untick the AVG toolbar and just install AVG without it.