# Searching on bing due to installation

Tags: google-chrome

I installed a few programs, and then chrome started using bing as a search tool.

I want to get back to using google, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the new tab page has been reset. Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/468524/chrome-new-tab-page-changed-but-i-want-it-back

Answer (score 0):

Click on the box in the upper right corner containing 3 horizontal stripes, then click Settings. There you can choose your default search engine, under "Search".

Comment: does not change it